# How to write this query in SQL with category and date sum

Tags: sql

I have a table in MySQL with these data belows:

```
  DATE       Category   AMOUNT
2016-1-1       A         12
2016-1-1       B         10
2016-1-2       A         5
2016-1-3       C         1
2016-2-1       A         5
2016-2-1       B         6
2016-2-2       A         7
2016-2-3       C         3
```

How can I get the result as below:

```
MONTH      TOTAL    Category-A  Category-B  Category-C

2016 Jan    28        17          10          1     

2016 Feb    21        12           6          3
```

Comment: What is relation between your data and expectation?

Comment: I presume you are joining another table for the desired result with the Category field as primary key. Kindly post the requirement promptly.

Comment: Also what database software are you using? MySQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, etc

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Which result do you need to get in words, not final state of query execution ? Which database you are using  ?

Comment: I'm using MySQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using MySQL this would work:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(DATE, '%Y %b') AS MONTH,
    SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL,
    SUM(IF(CATEGORY='A', AMOUNT, 0)) AS `Category-A`,
    SUM(IF(CATEGORY='B', AMOUNT, 0)) AS `Category-B`,
    SUM(IF(CATEGORY='C', AMOUNT, 0)) AS `Category-C`
FROM your_table
GROUP BY MONTH;
```

For other database engines you might have to change that a little.

Comment: I think you can try to use pivot.

Comment: You may use `EXTRACT( YEAR_MONTH FROM date )` instead of `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y %b')`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    (DATE varchar(8), CAT varchar(1), AMOUNT int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (DATE, CAT, AMOUNT)
VALUES
    ('2016-1-1', 'A', 12),
    ('2016-1-1', 'B', 10),
    ('2016-1-2', 'A', 5),
    ('2016-1-3', 'C', 1),
    ('2016-2-1', 'A', 5),
    ('2016-2-1', 'B', 6),
    ('2016-2-2', 'A', 7),
    ('2016-2-3', 'C', 3)
;


Select  Months,
[A][Category-A],
[B][Category-B],
[C][Category-C],
SUM([A]+[B]+[C])TOTAL
 from (
select CAST(year(DATE) AS VARCHAR)+' '+CONVERT(CHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, date))Months,
CAT,
AMOUNT 
from @Table1)T
PIVOT (SUM(AMOUNT) FOR cat IN ([A],[B],[C]))P
GROUP BY Months,[A],[B],[C]
ORDER BY CONVERT(CHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, Months)) desc
```